# WEMOS D1 wake up by button

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am asking for help, how can I WEMOS D1 wake up with the button? I know how to do this after some time using:

```
ESP.deepSleep (180000000)
```

Please help.

Comment: use reset button. in deep sleep the esp8266 is complete off. only RTC is running and sets io 16 LOW if there is time for wake-up. io 16 must be wired to reset for wakeup from deep sleep

Comment: Can you write something more how to do it?

Comment: there is nothing more. but it should by " io 16 must be wired to reset for wakeup from deep sleep by timer"

Comment: What is `ESP.deepSleep`? Possibly you mean node.dsleep() https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/node/#nodedsleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your button between RST and GND. Pressing the button will reset (and therefor wake up) the Esp ...

Comment: Will this action not damage WEMOS D1?

Comment: No. Being pulled to GND (for a short time) for hardware reset is what the RST Pin is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/node/#nodedsleep

> This function can only be used in the condition that esp8266 PIN32(RST) and PIN8(XPD_DCDC aka GPIO16) are connected together. Using sleep(0) will set no wake up timer, connect a GPIO to pin RST, the chip will wake up by a falling-edge on pin RST.